# How to get Operating System of all the computers on a domain using PowerShell 2.0 or Command Line?

Tags: command-line, dns, active-directory, operating-system, powershell-2.0

For all the computers on the domain I need the computer names and the OS they are running.

I am aware of `Get-ADComputer` cmdlet in PowerShell. But the issue is that the server is running Windows Server Enterprise Service Pack 2 2007 and PowerShell version 2.0.
Since, this is our main DNS server I do not want to download anything on it. I do not want to install .NetFramework then install PowerShell 5.0 or higher then install the cmdlet modules.
PowerShell 2.0, and Windows Server Enterprise Service Pack 2 2007 are so archaic that I can barely find any information on how to use these two together for what I am looking for.

Is there any way to get this information the old school way from the command line or from PowerShell ver 2.0?

Using Powershell or the command line is not necessary if there is a way to get the required information from AD that would be good too. I only mention PowerShell because my research hasn't shown that you can get this information directly from AD.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You may just get what you need using filters and the export function in Active Directory Users and Computers. Check out https://www.codetwo.com/admins-blog/export-users-from-active-directory/